# Get the event.target value with using parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In my project, I have 4 divs and to get the value of 4th div value, I have to do as:

```
event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.value
```

So when I change any UI change, then the value reference looses and the application crashes.

So is there any alternative solution to get rid off this methodology and get the value irrespective of the UI changes.

[image]

As in the image, if I need to get the value of the input text box, I need to drill down from admitted class to the input element using `event.target`.

For example:

```
event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
            .parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#Username").value
```

Comment: Where's your code? What event are you referring to? Where is this code that you are talking about inserted?

Comment: event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#Email").value
For Eg: to get the input value of the email  i need to use this piece of code...So in future if there is any new div or any new element is added the this code breaks

Comment: Assuming you've got a reference to the element which raised the event (which I presume you do as you tagged the question with 'jQuery') then you can just do `$(this).closest('.targetElementSelector').val();`

Comment: Don't add your code as a comment. Go back and edit your question with all the relevant information. And, add **all** the relevant code (HTML too).

Comment: *"...is there any alternative solution to get rid off this methodology"* Of course there is, but exactly which solution to use will depend on the  situation. You need to target the desired element *somehow*, so if not by the number of ancestors, then it'll have to be something else logically related to your DOM.

Comment: `event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.value` makes no sense, only form elements have a `value` property and they can't have any child elements.

Comment: @RakeshShastry: There are many, many ways to go about traversing the DOM and performing selections on it. So again, it will always depend on the exact details of the specific situation at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **event delegation** to take advantage of **bubbling**. In this case, you can use `e.delegateTarget` to get the parent.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#parent').on('click', '.children', function (e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

#child-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#child-3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1" class="children">
    <div id="child-2" class="children">
      <div id="child-3" class="children">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```